# Accessing an object inside of an array inside of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to write a function that accesses an object inside of an array inside of an object and then push that into an array.

This is the code I have right now:

**Javascript**

```
stuff: function (index1, index2) {
    for (var i = 1; i < index1.length; i++) {
        state[index2].push(foodData[index1][i].name);
    }
}
```

When I run storage.stuff('ingredientsToInclude', 'desired') I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

However, if I access foodData["ingredientsToInclude"][1].name in the console it returns the correct value.

Not sure the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: What is `index1`? Why are you using its length property as the limit for the `for` loop? Shouldn't that be `fooData[index1].length`?

Comment: The variable `i` iterates `index1`, so you probably want `index1[i]` somewhere. Try `foodData[index1[i]]` instead of `foodData[index1][i]`

Comment: Can you post a json example?

Comment: change `for (var i = 1; i < index1.length; i++) {` to `for (var i = 1; i < foodData[index1].length; i++) {`

Comment: @Amit.rk3 - This worked.  If you make it an answer I'll mark the question as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looping over string `'ingredientsToInclude'` instead of actual array `foodData['ingredientsToInclude']`.
So change for `(var i = 1; i < index1.length; i++) {` to for `(var i = 1; i < foodData[index1].length; i++) {`